# Difference between element.isDisplayed() and wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

Tags: selenium

I am trying to use WebDriver's fluentAPI, and am slightly confused with the choices available. I want to wait for an element to become visible. I undertsand that there are many ways available to do this, but I want to specifically understand the difference between the below two methods :

```
 (1)new FluentWait<WebElement>(webElement).
            withTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            pollingEvery(pollingTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            untilwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

(2) public void waitForWebElementFluently(WebElement webElement) {
    new FluentWait<WebElement>(webElement).
            withTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
            pollingEvery(pollingTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            until(new Predicate<WebElement>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(WebElement element) {
                    return element.isDisplayed();
                }
            }
            );
}
```

What is the difference between using isDisplayed, and visibilityOf?

Answer (score 11):

`isDisplayed` :

Is this element displayed or not? This method avoids the problem of having to parse an element's "style" attribute. 
[Source](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed%28%29)

---

`visibilityOf`

An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
[Source](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement%29).

---

So Visibility covers the condition of the element being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Amey already said the most of what there is to say, but I would add that the first method returns you the element that you are polling once it is visible, second is returning boolean. 
Anyway, I would recommend using the first on, because it is already taking care of staleness, if you look at the source:

```
  public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated(
      final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
      @Override
      public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          return elementIfVisible(findElement(locator, driver));
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }
```